# Gcloud and Docker: Pushing images is failing because of insufficient space

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I am trying to upload a 2GB Docker image to the Google Container registry:

```
gcloud docker push eu.gcr.io/project-id/image
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to generate layer archive: write /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/graph/_tmp/be959f8b6f706fb75cdc24b/28450517: no space left on device '''
```

Another problem I encountered is a about a failing push. It seems the upload has not worked and then I cannot push it again:

```
Error response from daemon: push eu.gcr.io/project-id/image is already in progress
```

By the way is there an option to list all images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is talking about space on your local device.  You should clear out any old images you have locally that you no longer need.

You can see your list of images in the Google Developers Console:
   https://console.developers.google.com/

Find your project, then select "Compute > Container Engine > Container Registry".  As of today, there is no way to list your images from the CLI.

Hope that helps, also feel free to reach out to us at gcr-contact@google.com

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now I saw that the files were buffered before the push and it seems I ran out of space.