# gcloud docker push no space left error

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Been using **google container registry** and **google container engine** for some time with my own created deploy script. It's been running ok for a while, but today I suddenly get periodic errors like this:

```
Failed to generate layer archive: error creating aufs mount to /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9cbd0e528da716d242de0c57a5cca94098e7746e32507b43c50571f5d3dc3d1d: no space left on device
```

What I don't understand is how these "devices" can be filled up, since they are buckets in the cloud. Is it a bug with Google Cloud or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

That error is about space on your local device. Try cleaning up old images or otherwise freeing up space locally.

[Here](http://jimhoskins.com/2013/07/27/remove-untagged-docker-images.html) is a good link with some useful cleanup commands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099786/gcloud-and-docker-pushing-images-is-failing-because-of-insufficient-space looks like a very similar question.